# Changing single language software to bi-lingual

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am having a huge Hospital Management Software with more than 500 screens developed in PHP and back-end SQL Server. Now I want to change the HMS into Bi-lingual. Currently all the screens are static i.e. the labels/text on the screens are not coming from DB but are hard coded. Something like the below Screen Shot.

[image]

In the above screen all the texts "LOGIN", "Username", "Password", etc. are hard coded.

My question is what would be the easiest method to adopt to change the texts dynamically.

1. Shall I create a table with column names in both the languages and then change the labels one by one
2. Or some other ideas

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't change any column names! Store texts/labels in a table, with labelid and languageid for each label/languange combination. Then you can add languages later if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I've seen is to create separate language files

For example

```
public_html
    /lang
        /en
            lang.php
        /fr
            lang.php
```

Each file contains an array

```
en/lang.php
$lang = array(
    'login-title' => 'Login',
    'username-label' => 'Username'
);

fr/lang.php
$lang = array(
    'login-title' => 'Entrer',
    'username-label' => 'Pseudo'
);
```

(Don't judge me I used google translate!)

It is important to note that the array and it's keys are named EXACTLY THE SAME in each file, only the values change.

Now using some session variable, or maybe by parsing the URL for a language parameter you can load the appropriate language file and as the array keys are exactly the same you can echo each one respectively.

```
echo $lang['login-title'];
```

One thing I particularly like about this approach is if you need a translator to do the work, you can just send them the file and as it's a very basic format they can generally implement the changes directly into the array. (with minimal guidance)

Comment: I suppose my array will increase more than 5000 elements. Will it effect the speed of the software?

Comment: Yes it will, will it be humanly noticeably? I doubt it, but you may want to benchmark the speed of the application before and after. I don't know this for a fact but I imagine that accessing an array (by loading a file on the filesystem) would be quicker than returning 5000+ rows from a database query and creating an array from that and then accessing the array.